# Differentiating between elements with same id, name and class

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get each content's height..

but how can I get element..

here is **html** code

```
<div class="same_name">
<div name="show_img"><img src="img_url1"></div>
<div name="content" id="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="same_name">
<div name="show_img"><img src="img_url2"></div>
<div name="content" id="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="same_name">
<div name="show_img"><img src="img_url3"></div>
<div name="content" id="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="same_name">
<div name="show_img"><img src="img_url4"></div>
<div name="content" id="content">content</div>
</div>
```

and **script** is..

```
<script>
$('.same_name').each(function(){
 console.log($(this)[0]);
 and..??
});
</script>
```

I sucess get each other_people
but how I can get each content's object

please help me.

Comment: Your html and script does not match

Comment: You do not have the class `other_people` in your example...

Comment: @thanks thanks *(I am glad I got to write that)* :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get elements with specific name.

```
$('[name="content"]').each(function(){

});
```

Comment: He needs to read some book about jquery and javascript not your ready made code.

Comment: @Phoenix completely agree. This question is beyond basic, but thank you, Adil, for taking the time to answer.  I feel a vote to close this question is in order however.